# Error: set failed: value argument contains undefined in property 'qt7UElH2j3hgGS1Ydm47gKiGd1L2.e762b4e234c.nome'

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

i  was trying to make a program with firebase, where I integrate the database from the database in real time with the authenticator.
I'm using expo to deploy my program, coding logo on pc and expo display for data on mobile.
However, when I try to register some data on my cell phone, it returns: **"Error: set failed: value argument contains undefined in property 'qt7UElH2j3hgGS1Ydm47gKiGd1L2.e762b4e234c.nome'"**
but on the computer it registers normally without returning any error.
I already tried to put it as "name: name || null" but it always returns empty in the database...

```
export const PetRegister = () => {
    const [nome, setNome] = useState('')
    const [idade, setIdade] = useState('')
    const [raça, setRaça] = useState('')
    const [pelos, setPelos] = useState('')
    const navigation = useNavigation()

    const writeToDatabase = () => {
      const uidd = uid();
      set(ref(dbPet, `/${auth.currentUser.uid}/${uidd}`), {
        nome: nome,
        idade: idade,
        raça: raça,
        pelos: pelos,
        uidd: uidd,
      });
    }
```

so I'm getting really worried because I need to deliver this work to pass the college semester and I'm already getting desperate... if anyone can really help me or call me on discord I'd appreciate it! _4reku#9030

[image]

Comment: From the error message you get, it seems that you `nome` variable doesn't have a value. If you've verified that it *does* have a value, even when you get this error, edit your question to show the code that you used to verify this.